# Storyline 360 - Get element in drop target through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, articulate-storyline, articulate

I was wondering if it was possible to get an element which is in a drop target through JavaScript in Storyline 360.
The situation is the following: I got 20 elements and 20 drop targets (numbered from 1 to 20). This allows the user to drag any element onto any target, resulting in a custom order for these 20 elements (e.g. element 1 on target 18, element 2 on target 10, element 3 on target 5, ...).
Now I am trying to save that order in a JavaScript object to create a PDF of it (using JSPDF), something like that:

```
var elementObject = {
  1: "element 8",
  2: "element 12",
  3: "element 5",
  4: "element 19",
  ...
};
```

Since you can only determine wheter an element is dropped on a correct or an incorrect target in Storyline, I can't use Storyline's native functionalities for this. Every drop target is the correct one, since you can freely set a custom order.
Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or a workaround to get that result? Doesn't have to be tidy and clean, just working :)